# Issue with latest gradle 5.4.1 - unescaped apostrophe in string

Tags: android, gradle

This is our old gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

With the above gradle, we are able to use the following string resource

```
<string name="reminder_doesnt_work_description"><![CDATA[doesn't]]></string>
```

But, if we were upgraded to latest gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

We will get the following error

```
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\yocto\noteplus\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:696:5-81: AAPT: error: unescaped apostrophe in string

        C:\yocto\noteplus\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:696:5-81: AAPT: error: not a valid string.
```

Any idea why such error happen?

Take note, both gradles able to handle string without single quote.

```
<string name="reminder_doesnt_work_description"><![CDATA[doesnt]]></string>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a backslash to escape the apostrophe as what the error log indicates instead of using CDATA?

Comment: You should escape the apostrophe using
`<string name="reminder_doesnt_work_description">doesn\'t></string>`.
Otherwise you can use: `<string name="reminder_doesnt_work_description"><![CDATA["doesn't"]]></string>`

Comment: Our string is much more complicated than the example shown. We expect no escaping is required if CDATA is used.

Comment: I've encountered this behavior and I'm still puzzled why this happens. Why do previous versions of gradle work with supposedly invalid strings?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too with unescaped apostrophes in a string resource also using CDATA after Android Studio upgrading my project from Gradle 5.1.1 to 5.4.1.

Funny thing is that after I fixed these AAPT errors by escaping the apostrophes with backslashes, the CDATA text in the string resource lost its carriage returns when being displayed in the app, and appeared just like one huge block of text.

Problem went away when I downgraded back to Gradle 5.1.1

Based on this behavior, I suspect that there is a bug with the way Gradle 5.4.1 is integrated with the Android Studio, causing it to ignore the CDATA token.  And so the resource contents are being treated as if no CDATA token is specified.  The bug may not be in Gradle itself but its AAPT plugin or some configuration in-between.

I filed an Android Studio bug on this at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145430021

I say for now just downgrade Gradle back to 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace all ' in your string resource to \'

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just escape the string as `AAPT2` demands it?

```
<string name="reminder_doesnt_work_description">doesn\'t</string>
```

[`CDATA`](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) sections in XML are meant to be skipped by the XML parser, but this obviously doesn't apply in this case, because that `CDATA` "section" is within the text-content of a node (and therefore this has zero effect, because it does not contain any node). And if you really would like to use `CDATA`, then at least encode the `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;` (but this still requires escaping the apostrophes).