# Groovy XmlParser How to handle quotes in strings?

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I try to create a groovy script to update my Android strings.xml files from my translations database, but when translated string contains quotes, I'm unable to get an valid and working xml output.

Example:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xml = "<xml><node>the example</node></xml>"
def parser = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)

parser.node[0].value = "l'éxemple"
println new XmlUtil().serialize(parser) // Invalid, quote character isn't escaped 

parser.node[0].value = "l&apos;éxemple"
println new XmlUtil().serialize(parser) // Quote character is now escaped twice (&amp;apos;)
```

Comment: @ou_ryperd Exact (see the comments in the code) I want to get this result: `<node>l&apos;éxemple</node>`

Comment: I misunderstood your question. Yes, it seems to escape the & from &quot with &amp. Looks like a bug in XMLUtil to me.

Comment: @ou_ryperd Android's resource compiler needs escaped quote in strings `3-399: AAPT: error: unescaped apostrophe in string` However you're right `l'éxemple` seems a valid xml string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: Not an Android dev, but I would do a replaceAll() on the XML after adding the node :-/

Comment: Quote should not be escaped. Why do you think it should?

Comment: @daggett Because of this error: `3-399: AAPT: error: unescaped apostrophe in string`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57984642/issue-with-latest-gradle-5-4-1-unescaped-apostrophe-in-string

Answer (score 0):

Solved, thank to @dagget

`parser.node[0].value = "l'éxemple".replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")`